# Regex pattern with different rule at end of string?

Tags: regex

The pattern should match word with capictal letter .

words are seprated with `[ ]+`

But the last word should not have `[ ]` after it.

there is no limit of number of the words.

I have managed to do :  (http://regexr.com?32s1h)

```
^([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+([a-z]+)?[ ]+)+$
```

which is Working for `Xav Tvc Dcc_` //notice the last space

but not for `Xav Tvc Dcc`

How can i fix my regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If space behind the last word is optional, use regex pattern

```
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*(?:[ ]+|$))+$
```

...and if there should not be a space behind the last word, then go with

```
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*(?:[ ]+(?=.)|$))+$
```

Comment: why did you use `?:` ( the uncaptured group) is that matters here ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - To optimize resources, as we do NOT need system to remember such group

Answer (score 1):

Require a word *not followed by a space* at the end:

```
^([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+([a-z]+)?[ ]+)*[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+([a-z]+)?$
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:> 'Xav Tvc Dcc ','Xav Tvc Dcc' -match '^([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+([a-z]+)?[ ]+)*[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+([a-z]+)?$'|%{"<$_>"}
<Xav Tvc Dcc>
```

If you're worried about possible errors introduced by changing the regex you could always construct it on the fly:

```
var word = "([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+([a-z]+)";
var regex = string.Format("^({0}?[ ]+){0}$", word);
```

Or similar for whatever language you use.

Comment: I thought about that solution , But I didnt want to duplicate the pattern....(talking about the first answer)

Comment: The second doesn't work anyway for reasons unknown right now, so I removed it.

Comment: And you could always construct the complete pattern out of sub-patterns to avoid change errors or code duplication.

Comment: any sample for your last comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
^([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s?)*
```

Show [Here](http://regexr.com?32s20)

And then run a trim operation to remove the trailing spaces?